# How can I use Scanner on switch case for String of array so that case takes in value from String b

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

How can I use Scanner class in "switch case" to determine the result;

Goal is to be able to use Scanner to determine the case. When user will input value in the scanner the select case will be able to use that String value (e.g if user type Mocking Bird in the Scanner it will be recognized in the switch case and out the code

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String b = input.next();

    String Books[] = { "Harry Potter", "To Kill a Mocking Bird", "Hunger Games" };

    for (int t = 0; t < Books.length; t++) {

      switch (Books[t]) {

        case "Harry Potter":
         System.out.println("Getting from switch case " + t + " " + Books[t]);
             break;

        case "To Kill a Mocking Bird"        
         System.out.println("Getting from switch case " + t + " " + Books[t]);
              break;

        default:
            break;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to java documentation `switch` statement works on specific paths:

> Unlike if-then and if-then-else statements, the switch statement can
>   have a number of possible execution paths. A switch works with the
>   byte, short, char, and int primitive data types. It also works with
>   enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types), the String class, and a
>   few special classes that wrap certain primitive types: Character,
>   Byte, Short, and Integer.

in your case you have more than one option to solve your problem either use `if` statement which is the better solution or use `switch` statement but you should put all cases of your `Books` array in the switch statement:

**Option1 if statement:**

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String b = input.nextLine();
    String Books[] = { "Harry Potter", "To Kill a Mocking Bird", "Hunger Games" };

    for (int t = 0; t < Books.length; t++) {   
        if(b.equals(Books[t])){
            System.out.println("Getting from switch case " + t+1 + " " + Books[t]);
        }
    }
```

**Option2 switch statement:**

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String b = input.nextLine();

    switch (b) {
        case "Harry Potter":
         System.out.println("Getting from switch case 1 Harry Potter");
             break;

        case "To Kill a Mocking Bird":       
         System.out.println("Getting from switch case 2 To Kill a Mocking Bird" );
              break;

        case "Hunger Games":       
         System.out.println("Getting from switch case 3 Hunger Games" );
              break;

        default:
          break;
    }
```

note that in switch case solution no need to use array Books because it's not suitable in this case.

hope this would help you.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use equals() to check the identity of Strings.
Use

```
   if (Books[0].equals(b)){
   ....
    }
   else  if (Books[1].equals(b)){
   ....
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you just need to change

> String b = input.next();

to

> String b = input.nextLine();

and change the switch to

`for (int t = 0; t < Books.length; t++) {
     switch (Books[t].equals(b)) {
        case true:
         System.out.println("Getting from switch case " + t + " " + Books[t]);
             break;
         default:
            break;
        }
     }`

or use if statement, it's better in this case

Comment: I think this solution not good for his case and it's bad practice.

it's against the purpose of switch statement is created

the better solution is to use if or define the cases of array books in the switch statement it self.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt to solve the problem @Rafik .. but @ Oghli is correct .